# C : strchr pointer value doesn't change

Tags: c, string, substring, strchr

I'm trying to recursively search for a substring in a string using C program. I wrote the following piece of code. The issue I'm facing is that, the `ptr` value, though it prints the correct value(using `puts` in the beginning of while), while usage its value is not changed! It uses the previous `ptr` value. I found this out using `gdb`. I couldn't figure out the cause of this. Kindly guide me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
void main()
{
   char buf[10]="hello",*ptr;
   char findc[10]="lo";
   int len,i,lenf,k,l,flag=0;

   lenf=strlen(findc);
   l=0,k=1;
   ptr=strchr(buf,findc[l]);

   while(ptr!=NULL)
   {
      puts(ptr);
      l++;
      for(i=l;i<(lenf);i++,k++)
      {
        if(ptr[k] != findc[i])
        {   
          flag=1;
          break;
        }
      }

      if(flag==1)
      {
        l=0;k=1;
        ptr=strchr((ptr+1),findc[l]);

        if(ptr==NULL)
        {
           puts("String not found");
           break;
        }

      }
      else
      {   
          puts("String found");
        break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not a recursive program, so you don't `recursively search for a substring`.

Comment: "Recursively"? Perhaps in the theoretical-computer-science-y sense. Also, `void main()` is not standard C. Last but not least, you never reset `flag`, so once it is set, the string is never found.

Comment: @n.m. Yeah, you are right! I didn't reset the flag. Now, it's working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a very simple mistake!

We'll have to reset the `flag` variable in the beginning of the `while` loop. This would solve the issue.

Thanks!